# How to get count for each row mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have Three tables

**1)review_trans**

**2)user_comment_trans**

**3)helpful_review_trans**

The table structure looks like this

### **review_trans**

```
 review_id(pk) |   review_desc  |  user_id 
 --------------+----------------+-----------
 1             |  hello world   |   1
 2             |  test2         |   1
 3             |  test3         |   2
```

### **user_comment_trans**

```
 comment_id  |   review_id  |     user_id
 ------------+--------------+------------
  1          |        1     |         4
  2          |        1     |         2
  3          |        2     |         3
```

### **helpful_review_trans**

```
 helpful_review_id |  review_id |  user_id
 ------------------+------------+------------
 1                 |     1      |     4 
 2                 |     1      |     2
 3                 |     2      |     3
```

I want count on each review for helpful votes and comments.
So output i want is like this

### **OUTPUT**

```
review_id       review_desc      count(helpful_review_id)      count(comment_id)
------------+------------------+----------------------------+--------------------
1           |    hello world   |           2                |           2
2           |    test2         |           1                |           1
3           |    test3         |                            |
```

Iam unable to get this record.I tried joining the tables but it only shows just one review_desc
Please advise and help.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join with count(distinct)

```
select r.review_id, 
r.review_desc,
count(distinct u.comment_id),
count(distinct h.helpful_review_id)
from review_trans r
left join user_comment_trans u on(r.review_id = u.review_id)
left join helpful_review_trans h on(r.review_id = h.review_id)
group by r.review_id
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baad3/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rt.review_id, rt.review_desc, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT hrt.helpful_review_id), COUNT(DISTINCT uct.comment_id)
FROM review_trans rt
LEFT JOIN helpful_review_trans hrt ON rt.review_id = hrt.review_id
LEFT JOIN user_comment_trans uct ON uct.review_id = rt.review_id
GROUP BY rt.review_id
```

Comment: You need `DISTINCT` in the counts, otherwise you'll multiply by the cross-product between the joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rt.review_id, rt.review_desc, helpful_count, comment_count
FROM review_trans AS rt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS comment_count
    FROM user_comment_trans
    GROUP BY review_id) AS uct ON rt.review_id = uct.review_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS helpful_count
    FROM helpful_review_trans
    GROUP BY review_id) AS hrt ON rt.review_id = hrt.review_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    review_trans.review_id,
    review_trans.review_desc,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            helpful_review_trans
        WHERE
            helpful_review_trans.review_id=review_trans.review_id
    ) AS helpful_review_id,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            user_comment_trans
        WHERE
            user_comment_trans.review_id=review_trans.review_id
    ) AS CountComment_id
FROM
    review_trans
```